# git https clone error "WARNING: failed to configure server name indication (SNI) TLS extension"

Tags: git, curl, https, clone, tls1.2

I installed and compiled curl and openssl.

Then I'm trying to `git clone` through https protocol.

When I execute `curl` command from terminal it works but when I execute `git clone`, it fails with error `WARNING: failed to configure server name indication (SNI) TLS extension`

Here is my curl version.

```
curl -V
curl 7.42.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.42.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2a zlib/1.2.11 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

When I git clone

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/test/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 192.30.255.112...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.255.112) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* WARNING: failed to configure server name indication (SNI) TLS extension
```

I'm using Cent OS 5.2.9

For some reason, I can't update OS version.

Is there anybody familiar with this issue??

`Cent OS v5.2.9
Git     v2.16.2
curl    v7.42.1
Openssl v1.0.2a`